# CSS3 Hover not working for a Button image to change

Tags: html, css, hover

I am completely clueless here. I have hover functions working fine on a nav menu with ul li but now I am trying to hover a single button, and after staring at my code for over 15 minutes, I do not get the clue...

This is my HTML:

```
<div>
      <a id="backbutton" href="services.html" title="Go back to Services">Go Back</a>
      <br />
</div>
```

This is my CSS3:

```
#backbutton {
display: block;
width: 200px;
height: 54px;
background: url('../images/BackButton.png') center center no-repeat;
text-indent: -9999px;    
}
```

This one above is working totally fine. Text is gone and the button displays properly. It's the below code that is not working

```
#backbutton a:hover {
background: url('../images/BackButtonHover.png') center center no-repeat;
width: 200px;
height: 54px;
}
```

The image will not replace for my targeted hover image (yes, it is uploaded on my server.)

Any clues?

Comment: `#backbutton` *is* the `<a>` element. It looks like you want `#backbutton:hover { ... }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#backbutton a:hover
```

to

```
#backbutton:hover
```

```css
#backbutton {
display: block;
width: 200px;
height: 54px;
background: url('http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/w/images/1/1c/OpenClosed.png') center center no-repeat;
 
}
#backbutton:hover {
background: url('https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTiC0kOjuPsNSp7qFgKtSZyccyZZtalf58MRnztInW19zW5WV8H1g') center center no-repeat;
width: 200px;
height: 54px;
}
```

```html
<a id="backbutton" href="#" title="Go back to Services">Go Back</a>
```

Comment: Awesome! It works fine now :) Despite I read the code at least 30 times, I did not notice that! Thanks a ton!!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to assign a `:hover` property to a link (`a` element) that is **below** the element with id `backbutton` in the hierarchy.

Instead of

```
#backbutton a:hover
```

use the selector

```
#backbutton:hover
```

and it should work. If you want to specify, that it only should affect the link with id `backbutton`, not any element with that id, use the selector

```
a#backbutton:hover
```